# What is the prayaschitta for failing to keep an Ekadashi fast?

Tags: fasting, prayaschitta, ekadashi

Is there any prayaschitta for not carrying out an Ekadashi fast in the scriptures?

Comment: just keep fast next ekadashi :) .. someone wanted to bathe in ganga, but he was hesitating to bathe and was waiting at its banks. A sadhu saw this and asked him why. he said 'before bathing in holy river, it is customary to first finish ablutions and bathe in local well water, out of respect for the river. But I couldn't find any well, so i'm afraid of committing sin by bathing in Ganga'. Sadhu replied 'Ganga will purify that sin too'.

Answer (score 4):

There is actually one. Because of Bhima's giant appetite he was not able to fast for a complete day, so Krishna explained that if could fast once a year on Jyestha Shukla Ekadashi, which is the hottest and longest solar day of the year, it would be equal to have fasted all the various ekadasis of the year. So, this is considered a sort of prayaschitta for breaking an ekadasi vow during the year, many considered this to remove the faults from previous year.

This account is given in the Brahma-Vaivarta Purana

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirjala_Ekadashi